# 2 монитора 2 рабочих стола manjaro

Tags: linux, archlinux, desktop, manjaro, monitor

Подключил 2ой монитор к рабочий станции. Работает по управлением Manjaro Linux KDE Plasma
Хочу привязать к каждому монитру виртаульные рабочие столы(команты), чтобы на 1 мониторе был рабочий стол 1, а на 2 второй соотвественно. Из коробки система предлагает только дублировать ихображение или растянуть на 2 экрана.

Comment: и два комплекта мышек-клавиатур?

Comment: Нет, но я же могу с одним монитором переключаться между рабоичими столами

Comment: так это тоже самое что ратянуть